# Convert col-span, row-span of table based layout to bootstrap responsive design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

Implemented the bootstrap for responsive design, but now the input requirement is as in attached jsfiddle.  System input is from Tabular layout , where user can add element in col span and row span , but when i am converting that to Div based responsive design it is not working. I tried the div solution but used absolute position and it will not work for responsive design. 
Any help to convert col-span, row-span of table based layout to bootstrap responsive design

Thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/V6gEL/

>

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-span">1</div>
<div class="left row-span">3</div>
    <div class="middle">4</div>

<div class="row-span " style="top=0px; left: 240px;">2</div> 


<div class="right col-span " style="top:240px; left:120px;">5</div>
```

CSS :

```
div{
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    float:left;
    top:0px;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
}

.right{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:Yellow;

}
.left{
     background-color:Red;
        top:120px;
}
.row-span{
    height:200px;
}
.col-span{
    width:200px;
}
.row{
    border:none;
    width:220px;

}

.middle{
    top:120px;
    left:120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the layout that you want (that is also responsive) can't be done with just css. You might be able to get a pinterest like layout on modern browser using CSS columns but its not supported by IE9 and lower and it doesn't fit your requirement (check out this [link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout)).

An alternative would be a javascript library like [jQuery masonary](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html) which allows for laying out odd shaped items and is responsive.